# How can you detect when a div has a class added/taken from it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a script which plays a sound when a div's class name is modified.

Take the following example:

```
<div class="move">1</div>
<div class="move">2</div>
<div class="move">3</div>
<div class="move active">4</div>
<div class="move">5</div>
```

It's a browser game, and whenever a new move is made, the "active" class name is moved to a different div tag, and removed from the current one. How can I detect this change with an event instead of constantly checking the status of the active div?

EDIT: I see you've marked my question as a possible duplicate. That does not answer my question, because I am trying to add functionality to an existing website, I cannot add my own event to the divs because the website itself is creating them.

Comment: Why wouldn't you trigger the sound from the same code that changes the class?

Comment: @BenSmith see my edit in the OP

Comment: @nnnnnn see my edit in the OP

Comment: Did you look at the second answer on that other question?

Comment: Ah, I see. Your question did not originally highlight the fact that you are trying to detect a change on a website where you cannot change the code.

Comment: How are you adding the class, classList?

Comment: When you say "I cannot add my own event to the divs" how restrictive is that - can you add for instance a jQuery plug-in, your own (manual) code, or do you even have access to the site (separate site) etc.  Please elaborate on the restriction/constraint.  The div creation being dynamic for instance is different from not being able to access them at all as you imply.